# How to fill empty cells in a GridView and make it non cickable

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-recyclerview

This is my GridView Code

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/device_display_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:background="#e5e5e5"/>
```

This is How my GridView Looks

my gridview

[image]

I am getting the data from the database and using that data to populate my GridView. My question is how can I make that blank view in the bottom right corner to appear with a white background. 
I also need to make my onItemClickListner not do anything if it's clicked. and suppose if I have 2 empty cells then both of them should be filled.

Comment: My sugggestion: Instead of `GridView` with background `#e5e5e5`, use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and `ItemDecoration` and `white` background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an extra empty objects in the last index of array.

```
 var emptycell=0
    if(array.size % 3 == 1) {
        array.add(EmptyObject())
        array.add(EmptyObject())
        emptycell=2
    } else if (list % 3 == 2) {
        array.add(EmptyObject())
        emptycell=1
    }
```

and when user click the any item you can check the clicked position should be lower then array.size - emptycell like below.

```
if(position<array.size-emptycell){
//do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use before receive your adapter:

```
if(list.size % 3 == 1) {
  list.add(YourModel())
  list.add(YourModel())
} else if (list % 3 == 2) {
  list.add(YourModel())
}
```

if you use RecyclerView in your adapter:

```
//onBind
if(item.someField == null) {
  holder.cover.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
  holder.cover.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}

//holder
fun setOnClickListener(item: YourModel) {
  if(item.someField == null) {
    vItem.setOnClickListener(null)
  } else {
    vItem.setOnClickListener(yourListener)
  }
}
```

It not best practice, it only fast idea.

P.S. Sorry at Kotlin, I haven’t written in Java for a long time